# insert into mysql file and it's directory using Python

Tags: python, mysql

I would like to combine file_name and directory to insert into MySql table using Python.

The code

```
cursor.execute("Insert INTO library (book_name, author, written, book_link, images) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, 'library/'%s, 'images/'%s )" , (book_name, author, written, book_link, images))
```

gives me unwanted single quote `'` symbols, like this:

`images/'me ibrary/'my life`

How to avoid this wrong syntax?

Comment: `CONCAT('library/', %s)`, or else prepend `'library/'` to the value of `book_link`, etc.

Comment: ("Insert INTO library (book_name, author, written, book_link, images) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, CONCAT('ibrary/',%s), CONCAT('images/',%s))" , (bookname, author, written, book_link, images)) - This works perfectly. Thank you very much!